# Question about Hensel's Lemma

Tags: solution-verification, hensels-lemma

A basic version of Hensel's Lemma states:

> Suppose that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and integer $k \geq 2$, and
> $p$ is  a prime, and $r$ is a solution of the congruence $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod
> p^{k-1}$. If $f'(r) \neq 0 \mod p$, then there is a unique integer
> $t$, $0 \leq t < p$, such that $f(r+tp^{k-1}) \equiv 0 \mod p^k$,
> given by
>
> $$t \equiv -f'(r)^{-1} \cdot \frac{f(r)}{p^{k-1}} \mod p$$  where
> $f'(r)^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f'(r)$ modulo $p$.

Now consider $f(x) = x^{10}+x-10$. Solving this in $\mod 2$ yields $r \equiv 0$ as a solution. $f'(x) = 10x^9+1$. We see $f'(0) \equiv 1 \neq 0 \mod 2$. It follows, by the lemma, that $f(0 + 2t) \equiv 0 \mod 2^2$ must be a solution. Since $k=2$ in this case and $f(r)\equiv0 \mod 2$, it implies $t \equiv 0 \mod 2$. So $f(0) \equiv 0 \mod 4$. But plugging in $x=0$, we get $f(0) \equiv -10 \equiv 2 \mod 4$. So clearly $x=0$ is not a solution to $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod 4$. Have I applied the theorem wrong? I have checked my work multiple times and unfortunately, I have not found my mistake.

Comment: This statement of HL does not line up with the one I found on wikipedia.  (You seem to take $m=0$ in wikipedia's version, which is not allowed as $m$ must be positive.)

Comment: My point was:  can you cite where you obtained this statement of HL?

Comment: The OP's statement of (one version of) Hensel's Lemma is correct.

Comment: The way you formulate HL has so much technical detail that it misses the key point: if you can solve $f(r) \equiv 0 \bmod p^{k-1}$ (where $k \geq 2$) with $f'(r) \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ then there is a unique $s \bmod p^k$ such that $f(s) \equiv 0 \bmod p^k$ and $s \equiv r \bmod p^{k-1}$: a root $r \bmod p^{k-1}$ has a unique lift to a root $s \bmod p^k$ when $f'(r) \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$. Leave the explicit formula for $s \bmod p^k$ out; it is revealed in the proof. Proof: the condition $s \equiv r \bmod p^{k-1}$ means $s \equiv r + p^{k-1}t \bmod p^k$ for some $t$.

Comment: So $f(s) \equiv f(r + p^{k-1}t) \bmod p^k$. Use Taylor's theorem to write the right side as $f(r) + f'(r)p^{k-1}t \bmod p^k$ since $p^{2(k-1)} \equiv 0 \bmod p^k$ (here we need $k \geq 2$). The condition $f(s) \equiv 0 \bmod p^k$ is equivalent to $f(r) + f'(r)p^{k-1}t \equiv 0 \bmod p^k$, and there's a unique such $t \bmod p$ since $f(r) \equiv 0 \bmod p^{k-1}$ and $f'(r) \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$, so you can divide all terms (including the modulus) by $p^{k-1}$ and then solve for $t$. All steps are reversible, so $t \bmod p$ is unique. QED

Comment: @AllenBell  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration in Hensel's is not done correctly in your computation. You want to lift your solution to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ so from $a_0=0$ you let $a_1=a_0+2b_1$, then $b_1$ will be given by $-a'_0/f'(a_0)\pmod{2}$ where $f(a_0)=a'_0\cdot 2$. In this case $f(a_0)=f(0)=-10=(-5)\cdot 2$, so that $b_1\equiv -5/1\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, and so $b_1=1$, and your lifted solution is $a_1=2$. Indeed
$2^{10}+2-10=1024+2-10=1016=254\cdot 2^2$. You can apply this same iteration to obtain higher approximations to a root in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.